# Import module "ipython" in Jupyter notebook

Tags: widget, ipython, jupyter

Can somebody please help me loading the ipython module into jupyter notebooks?

[image: This is what I get when trying to load it]

Answer (score 1):

`ipython` is a dependency for Jupyter, so it's already installed.

It looks like you're trying to import ipython widgets (`ipywidgets`) for use in Jupyter. To do this, in your shell (outside of Jupyter) install ipywidgets:

```
pip install ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Then import widgets:

`import ipywidgets as widgets`

[Read the docs to learn more about installing and using ipython widgets.](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked out well. However, I face the problem with other packages (e.g. numpy). `jupyter nbextension enable --py numpynbextension` did not work out to allow access through Jupyter. Any ideas on this :)?

Comment: Also,  I am still not able to run the code:
`from Ipython.display import display
display(text)` although you are saying that the ipython dependency is already installed?

Comment: try `pip install numpy` in your conda environment

Answer (score 0):

I believe that part of the problem is the capitalisation of the IPython package in your import statement:

try: `import IPython.html.widgets`

I don't know if that will get you everything you want, but that's probably the issue regarding your import.